# Add tabstop in python expression in UltiSnip

Tags: python, vim-plugin, ultisnips

I made a modification of the example given by UltiSnip doc:

```
snippet "be(gin)?( (\S+))?" "begin{} / end{}" br
\begin{${1:`!p
snip.rv = match.group(3) if match.group(2) is not None else "something"`}}${2:`!p
if match.group(2) is not None and match.group(3) != "proof":
    snip.rv = "\label{"+t[1]+":}"`}
    ${3:${VISUAL}}
\end{$1}$0
endsnippet
```

which, compared to the original one add a `\label{envname:}` and if the `envname` is `proof` then we didn't add it. This can be helpful when we write `thm` environment, e.g.

`be lem<tab>` will give

`\begin{lem}\label{lem:}
 <c-j>
\end{lem}`

the only drawback is that, I don't know how to add a placeholder at the position `\label{lem:$4}`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I get a work version, but not clean in code:

`` snippet "be(gin)?( (\S+))?" "begin{} / end{}" br
\begin{${1:`!p
snip.rv = match.group(3) if match.group(2) is not None else "something"`}}${2:`!p
if match.group(2) is not None and match.group(3) != "proof":
    snip.rv = '\label{'+t[1]+':'`$4`!p
if match.group(2) is not None and match.group(3) != "proof":
    snip.rv ='}'`}
    ${3:${VISUAL}}
\end{$1}$0
endsnippet ``